# how to make structure field names from cells

Tags: matlab

I have a textfile that I need to read into matlab. I want to implement something like a java LinkedHashMap in Matlab using structures. my textfile is like this

3-1 33.33 37.58

3-1 66.67 20.47

3-2 33.33 41.64

3-2 66.67 24.42

I read the entire file into array `[a,x,y]` where a is a cell array containing 3-1 ad 3-2

I need the structure to have its field names as a(1) or a(2) but unfortunately matlab gives me error. The reason is that I need to check if for instance a(1) is already a structure field name I concat the values to the previous values; if not, make a new field name with the respected values.  the code is:

```
[a,x,y]=textread('mytxt.txt', '%q%f%f','commentstyle','matlab');

s.a(1)=[x(1),y(1)];

for j=2:length(a)

    if isfield(s,a(1))==0

        s.a(j)=[x(j),y(j)];

     else

        temp = s.a(j);

        C = concat(1,temp,[x(j),y(j)];

        s.a(j) = C

    end

end
```

Comment: I'm confused by what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve. On what line is your error and what does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you want to have *s* as a structure with fields *3-1, 3-2, ..., 3-n*.  I also think you want to create using MATLAB's [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html).

To access the fields dynamically through the cells in the cell-array *a* you need to do something similar to:

```
s.(a{j}) = [x(j), y(j)];
```

Make a note of the different uses of parentheses *()* and braces *{}*. The parentheses are for indicating dynamic field-names as in *s.(str)* where *str* is a character array. The braces are used to index into the cell array *a* as in *a{j}* gives the character array of the jth cell in *a*.

Finally, your proposed field-names (*3-1, 3-2, ...* etc) are not legal MATLAB field-names because of the hyphen '-' and they do not begin with a letter, *[a-zA-Z]*. So, you need to replace the hyphen with another character, for example an underscore and append a letter to the start of the proposed field-name.

1. Replacing hyphen using *strrep* as in

   a=strrep(a,'-','_');
2. Appending a letter to the start of the field-name

   a=cellfun(@(str) ['a_' str],a,'uniformoutput',0)

This work can be done right after you finish reading the file into matrices *a*, *x*, and *y*